# Display data in tree structure in angular application

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

In my application I need to show data in the format of tree structure.

Basically I need to indent the item based on the parent_id's in the list so it creates a tree structure see below given screenshot where I indent based on where they are in the tree structure.

[image]

This is data that I am receiving:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Item 1",
    "parent_id": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Item 2",
    "parent_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Item 3",
    "parent_id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Item 4",
    "parent_id": null
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Item 5",
    "parent_id": null
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "title": "Item 6",
    "parent_id": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "title": "Item 7",
    "parent_id": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "title": "Item 8",
    "parent_id": 6
  }
]
```

I need some suggestions about how I can format this data so that it will be easy iterate over it and display it in frontend. Currently am thinking about creating a nested array of object where each object will hold its children like below.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Item 1",
    "parent_id": null,
    "child": [{
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Item 2",
        "parent_id": 1,
        "child": [{
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Item 3",
            "parent_id": 2
        }]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Item 4",
    "parent_id": null
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Item 5",
    "parent_id": null,
    "child": [{
        "id": 6,
        "title": "Item 6",
        "parent_id": 5,
        "child": [{
            "id": 7,
            "title": "Item 7",
            "parent_id": 6
        }, {
            "id": 8,
            "title": "Item 8",
            "parent_id": 6
        }]
    }]
  }
]
```

Comment: Correct, you can create nested array with required format

Comment: Yes array of objects will be enough for you and for this structure please use "Angular Hierarchical Tree View Component"

Comment: Do you want the solution to create the hierarchy ?

Answer (score 1):

You can mat tree. It's quite easy and useful. You can customise the design as per your wish using css. Official Documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview.